# Need help on Jargon Terms of Life Insurance Products

Tags: legal-terms

I am studying some documents on life insurance product, but I kept bumping into the jargon terms like "amount exposed", "policies exposed", "expected death QX7580E by amount", "expected death QX2001VBT by amount", "expected death QX2008VBT by amount", "expected death QX2008VBTLU by amount", "expected death QX2015VBT by amount." I tried very hard to search for the terms' meaning, but could not really explain why the first two terms have results that are **not** integers (amount exposed = money that are at risk of loss, policies exposed = insurance policies that are at risk of loss).

**Question:** Can someone please help clarify to me on what these terms truly mean, although I understand VBT = Valuation Basic Report Table, and QX stands for mortality rate? Really appreciate any help.

Comment: It's not the question you asked, but I would compare the premiums you pay with term life insurance and see what the "rate of return" on your whole life product is (how much you "earn" versus how much you pay in). I presume you know that you get either the investment amount or the insured amount, but not both?

Comment: @PeteB.: why is that? it's product-related question, no?

Comment: @DStanley: that's true. But why do you suggest me doing certain analysis:) Does it mean you understand all the jargons above?

Comment: @user177196 Because typically, whole life is sold as an "investment" but it has a horrible rate of return. Term life is a lot cheaper, and you can probably get better investment returns putting the difference in something else (and you get to keep both the insurance and the investment).

Comment: Also, I would recommend NOT "investing" in something you don't fully understand, so if there's a lot of "jargon" you can't get an answer to I would stay away. If you are pressured into buying, it means the salesman is worried about losing a large commission.